# How to transfer a file greater than 100mb using spring

Tags: spring, file, spring-mvc

How to transfer a file greater than 100mb using spring mvc.

I have been through the post [how to handle 100mb uploads for users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214888/how-to-handle-100mb-uploads-for-users), that tells to use ftp api. But want to know an alternative with spring.

Comment: How is Spring MVC relevant to this problem? It's not a replacement for FTP.

Comment: Are you trying to upload from client to server using a web-based form?

Comment: JoseK, Yes that is the possible scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation on Spring's support for multipart file uploads by doing a simple search, for example the documents pertaining to Spring 3.2.8's suport for multipart files can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart)

You'll need to define a multipart resolver for the project, see an example below, to be able to process multipart files.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

  <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
  <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

Once you've configured your application for `MultipartFile` support, there are a few things you'll still need to do (e.g. making sure you submit your forms as `multipart` forms, for instance).

```
<form method="post" action="/form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file"/>
  ...
</form>
```

After the form is submitted you should be able to handle it in the controller, similar to the example given in the above documentation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        // store the bytes somewhere
       return "redirect:uploadSuccess";
   } else {
       return "redirect:uploadFailure";
   }
}
```

Here you should be able to do byte-level and stream-level operations to manage the memory being used for larger file uploads, and anything else you need to do as it pertains to your business logic.

If you couple this with a front-end tool like BlueImp's [fileUpload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) (a jQuery plugin) you can create a nice interface that tracks the progress of your upload and gives you the ability to provide feedback to your users.